# How to create a coupon code in magento that will apply a percentage discount or a fixed value whichever is lower

Tags: magento

I want to implement a coupon code which will give the user 20% Off on their shopping cart if the value of the discount is less than 500.

e.g. Total Cart Value is 10000
20% coupon code applied would give a discount of 2000
However the maximum discount that should be given is only 500.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create two price rules. One will make sure that gives discount up £500, and the other will give £500 over the amount.

Now first code would have to work like this:

```
Apply Percent of product price discount: 20

//20% of £2500 = £500
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Price in cart  equals or less than  2500
```

then create another rule like this:

```
Apply Fixed amount discount for whole cart: 500

//Give discount of £500 if value is equal or greater then £2501
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Price in cart  equals or greater than  2501
```

This defo should do the trick you need ;)

Comment: Thanks Damek. My actual scenario is such: I am running a cash back scheme during a particular date period say 1st to 5th. The customer will be rewarded with discount coupons basis the slabs in which they purchase. 0 to 100 10%, 101 to 200 20%, 201 to 300 30%.....with a maximum cap of 500 irrespective of the discount code. so now when the customer purchases again during the redemption period (7th to 15th ) basis purchase history a coupon has been issued ...say 10%....now even if the customer purchases worth 75000..the maximum discount they get will be 500, .can this be done without code?

Comment: This is something definitely more complicated and I think what you really require is like a reward system, its your best option: [Magestore Reward System](http://www.magestore.com/rewardpoints/features.html/) alternatively you can maybe just create multiple percentage discounts.